# Take one action if mapmarker selected, another action if it is not

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a mapview with markers placed on it using an itemizedlayout.  If the user touches a point on the map that is not a marker, I want to execute action A, if the user selects a marker, then I want to pursue another action using the onTap method.  The problem is, every technique I use, I get both actions when the user taps the marker.  I would greatly appreciate any ideas on making this work. I would post code, but I all of the code I have tried fails simply due to it working as it should! :)  Any help appreciated.

I figured this out.. We have to call the superclass in onTap, then I use both onTap methods.. see code and comments.

```
public class MarkerMapOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

Context mContext;

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

public MarkerMapOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}


public void addOverlay(OverlayItem marker) {
    mOverlays.add(marker);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

public boolean onTap (final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView){
    //call the superclass, did it hit a marker?  If yes, it returns true onTap(index)
    //returned a marker and event is handled and we do stuff with the marker in onTap(index)
    if (super.onTap(p, mapView)) {
        return true;
    } 
    //We did not hit a marker, do other stuff and return the event has handled.
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "touch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
    return true;

}



@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you returning `true` from `onTap()` to indicate that you consumed the event?

Comment: Yes, I do return true.  I essentually have two MapLayers.  One is an itemized layer with the markers.  The other is just a plain layer that I call onTouchEvent on.. Below, in the one answer, I see that they are using OnTouchListener.. I will give that answer a try and report back.  Still, the problem I see is that the layers are not mutually exclusive, so If I tap on the marker, I will still fire the OnTouchListener and perform both actions.. I may not understand the below solution until I try it out though

Comment: "that I call onTouchEvent on" -- you don't *call* `onTouchEvent()`. The OS calls `onTouchEvent()`.

Answer (score 0):

For marker actions use `onTap` in `ItemizedOverlay`.

For other touch action use `onTouchListener` of your `mapView`:

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "touch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: So before I embark on implementing this, I am trying to make sure I understand.  When I touch the the marker, the OS will call onTap(), from there, I can do Task A.  But won't I also be interacting with the overlying mapView, and therefore won't the setOnTouchListener also see the tap, and call onTouch ALSO calling Task B? I only want Task A or Task B, NOT Task A AND Task B.  Thanks.

Comment: `onTap` should `return true` so `onTapListener` won't be called. I have tried this on one my project and it show AlertDialog when I touch marker, in other cases shows toast. Just copy upper code to your MapActivity and test it.

Comment: Awsome.  Thanks for the explanation.  I was not aware that onTap returning true would keep onTapListener from being called.  I'll go try and get it going!

Comment: Not working for me.  I updated my question to include the code I am using.  As stated.  When I click the marker, I still get the toast.  Thanks again.